# datetime datatype in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

Which data type can I use in Java to hold the current date as well as time?. I want to store the datetime in a db as well as having a field in the java bean to hold that.

is it `java.util.Date` ?

Answer (score 26):

`java.util.Date` represents an *instant* in time, with no reference to a particular time zone or calendar system. It does hold both date and time though - it's basically a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Alternatively you can use `java.util.Calendar` which *does* know about both of those things.

Personally I would *strongly* recommend you use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which is a *much* richer date/time API. It allows you to express your data much more clearly, with types for "just dates", "just local times", "local date/time", "instant", "date/time with time zone" etc. Most of the types are also immutable, which is a *huge* benefit in terms of code clarity.

Comment: My bad, got into the wrong doc.  My comment is obviously misleading, I will delete it.

Answer (score 12):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private String getDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: can i mapp it to timestamp in db(mysql)?

Comment: yes you can map time-stamp in db.  http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/mapping-mysql-data-types-in-java.shtml

Answer (score 7):

## java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later supplants both the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java and the Joda-Time library. The java.time classes have been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 and to Android.

The `Instant` class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours and possible minutes and seconds) to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "-04:00" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , offset );
```

Better yet is applying a full time zone which is an offset plus a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

## Database

Hopefully the JDBC drivers will be updated to work directly with the
java.time classes. Until then we must use the java.sql classes to move date-time values to/from the database. But limit your use of the java.sql classes to the chore of database transit. Do not use them for business logic. As part of the old date-time classes they are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

Use new methods added to the old classes to convert to/from java.time. Look for `to…` and `valueOf` methods.

Use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class for date-time values.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf( instant );
```

And going the other direction…

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

For date-time data you virtually always want the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type rather than `WITHOUT` when designing your table columns in your database.

Answer (score 3):

+1 the recommendation for Joda-time.  If you plan on doing anything more than a simple Hello World example, I suggest reading this:

[Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the RDBMS or even the JDBC driver.

Most of the times you can use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) most of the times along with a prepared statement:

```
pstmt.setTimestamp( index, new Timestamp( yourJavaUtilDateInstance.getTime() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this import:

```
import java.util.Date;
```

And declared my variable like this:

```
Date studentEnrollementDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, it seems like the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) standard library is the way to go. From [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) web page:

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

---

Back to your question. Were you to use Java 8, I think you want [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Because it contains the date and time-of-the-day, but is unaware of time zone or any reference point in time such as the unix epoch.

Comment: Right about using java.time but wrong about using `LocalDateTime`. Because it has no time zone or offset-from-UTC, it has no real meaning. It is not a moment on the timeline. Rarely needed in business apps. Instant, OffsetDateTime, and ZonedDateTime are all used to represent a moment on the timeline.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes that's a good rephrasing. Though the question at hand wasn't really specific enough to say what is right or wrong.

Comment: Agreed the Question is not clear, and rather anemic, lacking details. But it does say “current” date and time which almost certainly should be zoned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar.

```
     Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
```

[Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

[Date4j alternative to Date, Calendar, and related Java classes](http://www.date4j.net/)